# knitr with octave out.width does not restrict text out runs out of margin

Tags: r, octave, knitr, sweave

The following is the minimal reproducing example, if you use debian system, one can install octave by snap or apt easily.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\title{Minimal example of octave with knitr for Rnw file}
\author{Xudong Sun}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle

<<engine='octave', engine.path='/snap/bin/octave', results='markup', echo=TRUE, out.width=5>>=
  x = -10:0.01:10
@
\end{document}
```

The output text runs out of margin:

[image]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the white background ;)

F.e.:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\title{Minimal example of octave with knitr for Rnw file}
\author{Xudong Sun}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle

<<chunkName, echo=FALSE, comment=NA, background='#FFFFFF'>>=
x <- rnorm(100)
x
@
\end{document}
```

[image]

... but if you want to save "default dimensions of the bg area" you can use f.e:

```
<<chunkName, echo=FALSE, comment=NA, background='#FFFF33'>>=
options(width = 60)
x <- rnorm(100)
x
@
```

[image]